# How to get password of the Amazon aws rds user?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rds

I can see there is a user from my aws rds console,

```
AWS Console -> RDS -> Databases -> Configuration -> Availability
```

But I forgot what was the password of this user? **How can I see/ retrieve the password?** Moreover how can I add new users for my existing database?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think there is no way to recover the lost password, but you can Not sure you can recover, but you should be able to [reset](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/reset-master-user-password-rds/) it.

Creating new uses is done from inside the db. You login as a root, and they you create new users with their passwords using db-specific sql statements for that. For instance for mysql you have [CREATE USER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-user.html) statement.

Comment: what's the password for root?

Comment: Its the one when you setup your rds.

Comment: I was doing a lab on RDS today. I created an MSSQL server using RDS and made an auto generated password. Later, I was unable to locate the password anywhere and the lab instructions also didn't guide the password retrieval method. So I had to modify the password manually in order to connect to the DB instance through Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. Is there a way to retrieve the auto generated password?

Answer (score 3):

While not the default behavior of RDS, if you have configured an [integration with Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/improve-security-of-amazon-rds-master-database-credentials-using-secrets-manager/) then you could find the password there.

Autogenerated passwords may be found within `secrets`

```
AWS Secrets Manager > Secrets > auroraDbSecret-G32dfhIgOda5
```

Comment: RDS does not use SecretsManager by default. This answer is incorrect, unless you have setup SecretsManager integration with RDS.

Comment: You have to think about how your answer will help other people that land here looking for help. As it is, your answer is going to be really confusing to the 99% of people using RDS that haven't added the SecretsManager integration. If you edited your answer to say something like:  "while not the default behavior of RDS, if you have added an integration with SecretsManager then you could find the password there" then it would be clear and not add to people's confusion.